# Understanding Seasonal ARIMA

Tags: arima, stationarity, seasonality

I'm a bit struggling understanding the concept of Seasonal ARIMA. Because from what I've understood: when we modelize an ARIMA model, we want to transform the time series into a stationary series (especially by differentiating) thus, removing every eventual trend or seasonality.

So how can a seasonal ARIMA make sense if we have removed the seasonality?